# Is it possible to retrieve pod name from values.yaml file of helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Quite new to Helm. Currently, I create an env variable in a way that when I deploy my pod, I am able to see the pod name in the environment variables list. This can be done like so in the template file:

```
containers:
- name: my_container
  env:
  - name: POD_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Is it possible to do something similar in the values.yaml file (maybe in an extraEnv field?) and then use this value in the .tpl? Other configurations, like configmap names, depend on it, in order to be unique between pods and I want to easily retrieve the value like so:

```
volumes:
- name: my_vol
  configMap:
    name: {{ .Values.pathto.extraEnv.podname }}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not usually possible, since the pod name will be dynamically constructed including some random components (assuming a Deployment is managing the pod), and also because all of the Helm templating happens before anything is sent to Kubernetes.  What's different between the different ConfigMaps?  What's the ultimate goal of this setup?